# How to make a button change the contents of a Div

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the content of my Div so that when i click the button, it updates the content of the Input component. In this scenario, I want to click the button 1 and have it display 1 inside the div.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button.js";
import Input from "./Input.js";
import {useState} from "react";



function App() {

  const [text, setText] = useState(" ");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(" ");

  const handleScreen = (e) => {
    setText((text) + e.target.name)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Input results = {text} numbers = {result} > </Input>
      <Button name = "1" handleText = {handleScreen}> </Button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a default event listener that ReactJS provides to handle click events, which is `onClick`

Your code will be more or less this way:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button.js";
import Input from "./Input.js";
import {useState} from "react";



function App() {

  const [text, setText] = useState(" ");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(" ");

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setText((text) + e.target.name)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Input results = {text} numbers = {result} > </Input>
      <Button name = "1" onClick = {handleClick}> </Button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I copied your code, but it doesn't work